# Accessing SharePoint documents from different WebApplication Zones

Tags: document, alternate-access-mapping, word

I have a SharePoint 2010 Server site (`http://shpserver:81`) that I have extended twice:

Intranet: `http://partnernet.abc.local`
Internet: `https://partnernet.abc.com`

When I am on the internet (`https://partnernet.abc.com`) and I create a new Document from within SharePoint, Word 2010 starts up and I can save the document to SharePoint. However, the default template of SharePoint (template.dotx) is coupled to this document using the absolute url `https://partnernet.abc.com/testexternproject/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/Forms/template.dotx`

When I then go to the intranet (`http://partnernet.abc.local`) and I want to open this new  document from that location, Word 2010 takes very long to open the document and in the splashscreen of Word I can see that it tries to open the template file using the absolute location as mentioned above. This location is however not accessible from the intranet.

I first thought that it had something to do with the alternate accessmappings in SharePoint, but we have tried all different setups, until we realized that the location of the template was baked in the Word document with an absolute URL.

The alternate access mappings we use is (Internal URL - Zone - Public URL for Zone):

`http://shpserver:81` - Default - `http://shpserver:81`

`http://partnernet.abc.local:31081` - `intranet - http://partnernet.abc.local`

`http://partnernet.abc.local` - intranet - `http://partnernet.abc.local`

`http://partnernet.abc.com:32081` - internet - `https://partnernet.abc.com`

`https://partnernet.abc.com` - internet - `https://partnernet.abc.com`

I can not believe that we are doing something special.
What have we done wrong here?

Any suggestions are welcome.

---

**EDIT**:
Below I have supplied a possible solution. But I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier, we have an external accessible SharePoint Site which is published via Microsoft TMG. The internal facing SharePoint Site is not going via the TMG. Both sites however, are presenting the same information for potentially the same users.

We are now considering the following:

1. Install the SSL Certificate, which is now only installed at the TMG, on the IIS server as well,
2. redirect partnernet.abc.com to the IIS Server directly, bypassing the TMG, for internal users,
3. remove all references to partnernet.abc.local

Doing so will ensure that we will always access the SharePoint sites via the same URL, whether we are coming from the internet or intranet.